Non-inertial frames in quantum mechanics
In classical physics, non-inertial frames necessitate adjustments to Newton's laws due to acceleration and rotation, yet in general relativity, Einstein successfully incorporates such frames. Why does quantum mechanics typically avoid or neglect non-inertial frames, and how does it rely on inertial reference frames? Could this approach potentially impact its accuracy?

Related. See the answers, the comments and the references therein.

Hi Vishnu. Welcome to Phys.SE. General tip: Consider to only ask 1 question per post. I removed the 2 last questions.

Inertial forces are completely described, in Hamiltonian mechanics, in terms of an electric-like potential plus  a magnetic-like vector potential.
The Hamiltonian of a free particle in a non-inertial reference frame has the same structure of the Hamiltonian of a charged particle in a given electromagnetic field.
The quantization procedure is automatic then.

So there is some misunderstanding here, may be as I am not aware of it. Non-inertial reference frame in hamiltonian mechanics is related to quantum mechanics qed inertial reference in anyway?

Yes, at non relativistic level an inertial reference frame can be treated as an inertial one with some further "potentials" describing inertial forces. It does not matter if the system is classical or quantum... Once you know how to pass from Hamiltonian mechanics to quantum mechanics, you also know how to deal with non inertial reference frames in QM

Is it because it is easier to work with this approach than consider non-inertial reference frame or this approach gives flexibility to work with both the frames?

This approach gives  flexibility to work with both the frames. Obviously Physics has the last word. However, if you discovered that this approach does not work, you would find out some new quantum property of inertia, and  it would be a possible way toward quantum gravity...As far as I know no evidence in that sense exists.

Thank you very much for clarification

@Vishnu If this answered your question, consider to accept it.
